# Group by function and code needed for a data frame

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I am trying to match a variable in a particular column of a data frame and based on that carry out a function to in 2 other columns .

For example If I match column `"Product"` say VX I want to add all the corresponding rows that have "`Product"` VX and sum column "MV" and divide it by the sum of column `"Long/Short"`

```
=(110+55+112)/(2+1+2)
```

Hence I want to wrote a code for that in python to carry out that task.

```
Product    Long/Short     MV
VX            2          110
VX            1           55
6A            3           123
6C            1           43
VX            2           112
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what *exactly* do you want? A new dataframe? with what columns? or a Series?

Comment: I want a new data frame with the product andthe corresponding sum of Column "VX" divided by sum of column "Long/Short" for VX. E.g. VX =(110+55+112)/(2+1+2)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `groupby` and `sum` to sum the other columns by product:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['VX', 'VX', '6A', '6C', 'VX'],
                   'Long/Short': [2, 1, 3, 1, 2], 'MV': [110, 55, 123, 43, 112]})

tmp = df.groupby('Product').sum()

result = pd.DataFrame({'Ratio': tmp['MV']/tmp['Long/Short']}).reset_index()
```

It gives as expected:

```
  Product  Ratio
0      6A   41.0
1      6C   43.0
2      VX   55.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['VX', 'VX', '6A', '6C', 'VX'], 'Long/Short':[2,1,3,1,2], 'MV':[110,55,123,43,112]})
df
   Product  Long/Short   MV
0      VX       2        110
1      VX       1        55
2      6A       3        123
3      6C       1        43
4      VX       2        112

temp = df.groupby(['Product']).agg(ls_sum=('Long/Short', 'sum'), mv_sum=('MV', 'sum'))
temp 
         ls_sum  mv_sum
Product
6A            3     123
6C            1      43
VX            5     277

temp['avg'] = temp['mv_sum']/temp['ls_sum']
temp
         ls_sum  mv_sum   avg
Product
6A            3     123  41.0
6C            1      43  43.0
VX            5     277  55.4

new_df = temp.reset_index()[['Product', 'avg']]
new_df
    Product   avg
0      6A     41.0
1      6C     43.0
2      VX     55.4
```